# Capture query results using SQL Server Profiler

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, trace, profiler, sql-server-profiler

It's possible to capture a query's result using SQL Server Profiler?

i.e. the resultset generated by the query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to capture the results of a query using SQL Profiler.  You can view pretty much everything else though - includung the actual query executed, parameters and their values, query statistics etc.

Comment: I also do not know a way to do it in SQL Profiles. What I do is record the queries and then copy paste them in QA and re-run them. This is not ideal and not always possible but this is the only way I know it would work.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a new sql trace , and while doing that in the events tab of new trace 
de-select all and select only sqlstmntstarting, sqlstmntcompleted.

if you want to monitor procedures as well spstarting, spcompleted